# Data deleted from /mnt directory after stop and start EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Data deleted from /mnt directory after stop and start  EC2 instance

```
[root@localhost opt]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            9.7G  1.4G  7.8G  15% /
none                  1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb             394G  199M  374G   1% /mnt
```

I place my data in  /mnt  .I stop instance yesterday .
Afetr starting the instance today ,I didnt find any data form /mnt .
I have another from /opt .

How can i recover that data from /mnt .

If /mnt is  Temporary mounting point .Then how can i use these all space

Answer (score 4):

On `EC2`, `/mnt` directory is mounted to ephemeral storage.

After reboot or instance stop/start, all data is lost.

Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566223/what-data-is-stored-in-ephemeral-storage-of-amazon-ec2-instance).

Comment: Thanks, Then how can i use that space 374GB from /mnt

Comment: Personally, I don't find it useful. But you can use it for some not important temporary data.

Comment: is it possible to recover those data in /mnt

Comment: @user2439278: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

It is a common misconception that a reboot/restart will wipe the ephemeral storage - this isn't true.

You can try it yourself and see.

What will is a stop/start - that actually deprovisions your VM, and then moves it to another host machine - which will have wiped ephemeral drive(s) and then starts it up with your root ebs (at least) attached. Stop/start and reboot are often conflated - but they are very different things here.

Answer (score 1):

`/mnt` should really just be used for ephemeral data storage that is not critical if instance needs to be restarted.  This is actually well suited for things such as local on-disk cache, temporary data storage, etc. as this ephemeral storage will oftentimes perform better from an I/O standpoint than say an EBS volume mount.  Just understand that you should only place non-critical data there.