# Can I create swap file in the ephemeral storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

First of all, this is my `df -h` output:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1 7.9G 4.2G 3.4G 56% /
udev 1.9G 8.0K 1.9G 1% /dev
tmpfs 751M 180K 750M 1% /run
none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0% /run/lock
none 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb 394G 8.4G 366G 3% /mnt
```

I know that the /mnt is an ephemeral storage, all data stores in will be deleted after reboot.

Is it OK to create a /mnt/swap file to use as swap file? I add the following line into /etc/fstab

```
/mnt/swap1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

By the way, what's the /run/shm used to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not? Have you already tried?

Comment: @yegor256 Yes, It works well. But I'm wondering what could happen if I reboot the instance. Since the swap file is created on the ephemeral storage

Answer (score 0):

Ephemeral storage preserves data between reboots, but looses them between restarts (stop/start). Also see this: [What data is stored in Ephemeral Storage of Amazon EC2 instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566223/what-data-is-stored-in-ephemeral-storage-of-amazon-ec2-instance)