# ec2 ephemeral storage data recovery

Tags: amazon-ec2

Had some data on ephemeral storage of a ec2 medium instance. They are lost between server reboot. I had a ami created just before the reboot. Is it supposed to contain that data? I had created a new instance from that ami but can't find the data on new ephemeral drive.

ok. I got it. Create Image only creates ebs backed ami. Creating instance storage backed ami is different. It is described here [creating an instance store ami](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html)

Comment: How did you create the AMI?

Comment: from aws console, right clicking the ec2 instance and then create image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ephemeral drives on EC2 are, by definition, [ephemeral](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ephemeral). This means that their data in not kept between reboots, and not saved as part of the AMI image.

You can read more on what you can an cannot do with these kinds of disks [here](http://www.webadminblog.com/index.php/2010/03/23/amazon-ec2-ebs-instances-and-ephemeral-storage/).

Comment: its that here( [link]http://stackoverflow.com/a/11566285/1555414 ) someone stated "You can create an AMI from your current machine state, which will contain everything in your ephemeral storage. Then, when you launch a new instance based on that AMI it will contain everything as it is now."

Comment: ok. I got it. Create Image only creates ebs backed ami. Creating instance storage backed ami is different. It is described here [creating an instance store ami][1]


  [1]: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-instance-store.html

Comment: Wait, no.  The data on the ephemeral drives *does* persist across reboots.  It does not persist across an instance stop/start (which moves the instance to a different physical host) and of course doesn't survive termination... but across ordinary reboots, it absolutely should persist.

Comment: can amazon be requested to retrieve the data? just asking :)

Comment: @orchidit Ephemeral volumes automatically get formatted to make room for the next host on the hardware. Data recovery is not possible.

Comment: Michael is correct, and you might actually just need to remount the ephemeral drive(s) if all you did was reboot not stop/start. Depending on whether the mounting is done autmatically at boot or not. Check ls -l /dev/disk